# Gossip protocol in a Ring topology

Tags: algorithms, distributed-computing

I am implementing a gossip based membership detection mechanism. Lets say we have a ring topology, i.e. node1 only knows about the 2 nodes (node4 and node2) around it.

```
                node1
             -        -
          -              -
      node4              node2
          -              -
            -         -
               node3
```

Now, gossiping says: Pick a node at random from the membership list. But, if we strictly follow the ring topology, then node1 should only try to gossip with node2 or node4. Other wise, only for communication the topology will become a clique rather than being a ring.

Background: According to the Amazon dyanmo paper:

> Each node contacts a peer chosen at
>   random every second and the two nodes
>   efficiently reconcile their persisted
>   membership change histories.

If, that is the case, then is dynamo's implementation not following a "true" ring topology and only using ring for consistent hashing (replication) and using a clique for membership detection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example:

I don't think a node knows what his direct neighbors are. It just has 2 neighbors, it doesn't know which.

Node 4 wants to chat with node 3:

- Node 4 sends the message to node 1 (just the ring direction).
- Node 1 sees message is not for him so it passes it on to node 2.
- Node 2 sees message is not for him so it passes it on to node 3.
- Node 3 gets the message, sees it's for him and parses it.

"Gossiping" is where node 1 and 2 listens in on the conversation (which they help facilitate). By listening in they hear about a node 4 and a node 3, both can be added to their membership list.

Both node 1 and 2 can now ask node 4 and 3 what other members they know.

Say node 1 asks node 4 first. Node 2 and 3 will find out about node 1's existence by listening to the gossip.

Noone knows about node 2 at this point, but eventually it will also revealing it's presence by asking another node for it's membership list.

This doesn't break communication lines in any way.